# Delete rows using NOT IN

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite

How can I do a delete in flutter using NOT IN() ?
I have tried few ways but the app is always crashing :

- either it's closing the app with zero error or message :

**

```
await db.rawDelete('DELETE FROM ' +
      dao.tableName +
      ' WHERE ' +
      dao.columnUuid +
      ' NOT IN (' +
      params.join(',') +
      ')');
```

**

- or it gives me

  *Invalid argument ['2e73c330-1312-42fa-ad3b-d762f96b5ec7', '1ba3e7e3-2d57-4916-9ea5-2624432cf60c'] with type List.
  Only num, String and Uint8List are supported. See https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite_common/blob/master/sqflite_common/doc/supported_types.md for details
  This will throw an exception in the future. For now it is displayed once per type.

  ```
    await db.rawDelete(
              'DELETE FROM ' +
                  dao.tableName +
                  ' WHERE ' +
                  dao.columnUuid +
                  ' NOT IN (${('?' * (params.length)).split('').join(', ')})',
              [params]);*
  ```

  Params is a List of Strings : ['2e73c330-1312-42fa-ad3b-d762f96b5ec7', '1ba3e7e3-2d57-4916-9ea5-2624432cf60c']

I know about the SQL injection issue.
Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Yes, please do it with params and not with string construction!

Answer (score 0):

`params` is already a list but in your code you are using `[params]` (which is a list of list, hence the error displayed) instead of just `params`